# JDBC : display retrive data into table structure

Tags: java, jdbc

Hello m new in jdbc environmenti i connected to database and query db and get resultset . 
but now i want to display data in table view in java

how to achive ?

```
//STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;

public class FirstExample {
   // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "username";
   static final String PASS = "password";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String sql;
      sql = "SELECT id, first, last, age FROM Employees";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

      //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
      while(rs.next()){
         //Retrieve by column name
         int id  = rs.getInt("id");
         int age = rs.getInt("age");
         String first = rs.getString("first");
         String last = rs.getString("last");

         //Display values
         System.out.print("ID: " + id);
         System.out.print(", Age: " + age);
         System.out.print(", First: " + first);
         System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
      }
      //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      catch(SQLException se2){
      }// nothing we can do
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}//end main
}//end FirstExample
```

it gives following  output

```
ID: 100, Age: 18, First: Zara, Last: Ali
ID: 101, Age: 25, First: Mahnaz, Last: Fatma
ID: 102, Age: 30, First: Zaid, Last: Khan
ID: 103, Age: 28, First: Sumit, Last: Mittal
```

but i want output like specific table

```
ID | AGE | FIRST | LAST
-----------------------
101|     |       |
   |     |       |
```

Thanks

Comment: It's seems like just a matter of formatting your SOPs. Print the column headers before you enter the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before while :

```
String foramt = "%s\t| %s\t| %s\t| %s";
System.out.println(String.format(format, "ID", "AGE", "FIRST", "LAST"));
```

in while:

```
//Display values
System.out.println(String.format(format, id+"", age+"", first, last));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add rx2xml.jar file into your referenced libraries.
Import `net.proteanit.sql.*[enter image description here][1]` this package.
And create an object of JTable say t1.
Store the resultant table into the ResultSet object.
And execute this statement-->`t1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));`